# Is this panel or cross-sectional data?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

I have observations of taxi pickups for each hour and day in 2015 in NYC. 
I merged the taxi data with daily observations of weather and 2010 estimates of population and education of specific areas in NYC.
What type of data is this?
Panel or cross-sectional data?

Answer (score 1):

Panel.  Panel data is also called "longitudinal" data, as it involves a cross-sectional unit $i$ observed multiple times $t$.

It is called a "panel" because, when the matrix of data is sorted first by $i$ and then by $t$, there are "panels" of time series for each unit $i$.

Note that the cross section need not be an individual and the $t$ variable need not be time.  It could be classes in a school, for example, where you observe multiple schools, or penguins in a penguin colony, where you observe multiple colonies.

Typically with panels you apply methods that take advantage of the repeated observations, and that respect the fact that within-group observations are likely to be correlated.